# working with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string and I need first element to be captured.

```
s = extra-root, May 15, 2024, Entry, abcd: efgh
```

I am doing it as,

```
print s.split(",")[0]
```

But, is there any way using re to get the first element of string with comma? I want "extra-root".

Comment: Where is semicolon in first element?

Comment: Mmm that's a comma, not a semicolon.

Comment: `print(re.sub(r',.*', '', s))`

Comment: yup made mistake while writting. its comma

Comment: `print(re.search(r'([^,]*)', s).group(1))`

Comment: rock can you eplain how you did the same?

Comment: in the first one I am substituting everything after `,` with blank..in the second one I am capturing everything till we get first `,`

Comment: but there ae 2 groups now with name "extra-root". group(0) and group(1)

Comment: @sam well you can use `print(re.search(r'[^,]*', s).group())` also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a regular split function with if condition. If you want regex then `re.search` is the best choice which should return the first match.

```
>>> s = 'extra-root, May 15, 2024, Entry, abcd: efgh, ds:sd'
>>> [i for i in s.split(',') if ':' in i][0]
' abcd: efgh'
>>> next(i for i in s.split(',') if ':' in i)
' abcd: efgh'
```

or

```
re.search(r'[^,]*:[^,]*', s).group()
```

- `[^,]*` matches any character but not of `,`, zero or more times.
- `:` matches a colon.
- `[^,]*` matches any character but not of `,`, zero or more times.

Update:

To get the first element in a comma separated string.

```
re.search(r'^[^,]*', s).group()
```

- `^` start
- `[^,]*` Any char but not of comma , zero or more times. Now it should match an empty string if it's exists at the start but if you use `+` then it won't capture that empty string. Because `+` expects atleast one char to be exists.

Comment: please see I need output as "extra-root"

Comment: @sam wat? then why you specify about colon?

Comment: `re.search(r'^[^,]+', s).group()`

Comment: Thanks. why plus is used?